# Access Data from a Array of NSDictionaies in a Singleton Class and Displaying that data in a TableView (XCode))

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a Singleton Class that contains an array of NSDictionary (5 of them). I need to display this data in a different ViewController (I'm using Storyboard).

I can access the data if I 'm pulling data from an array but now I need to pull data from an array of NSDictionary. I came up with this line:

```
cell.textLabel.text =  [[[[Singleton sharedInstance] movies]  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas? I'll put my Singleton class and my TableView Class:

Singleton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface Singleton : NSObject {

    NSDictionary *batman;
    NSDictionary *superman;

    NSArray *superheoes;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *batman;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *superman;

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *superheroes;

+ (Singleton *) sharedInstance;
+ (AppDelegate *) sharedAppDelegate;

@end
```

Singleton.m

```
#import "Singleton.h"

@implementation Singleton

@synthesize batman, superman;

+ (Singleton *) sharedInstance {

    //The instance of this class is store here
    static Singleton *myInstance = nil;

    // We check to see if an instance already exists
    if (nil == myInstance) {
        myInstance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    }

    return myInstance;

}

-(id) init {

    if (self=[super init]) {

        batman = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                             @"name", @"Back to the Future", 
                             @"year", @"1985", nil];

        superman = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"name", @"Superman", 
                    @"year", @"1990", nil];

        superheroes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:batman,superman, nil]; 
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark access to app delegate etc.
+ (AppDelegate *) sharedAppDelegate; {
    return (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}



@end
```

SuperheroesDatabase.m

```
#import "SuperheroesDatabase.h"
#import "Singleton.h"

@interface SuperheroDatabase ()

@end

@implementation MovieDatabase

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    if(cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }


    cell.textLabel.text =  [[[[Singleton sharedInstance] movies]  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %i", indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: That should work, what doesn't work about it?

Comment: Apple will probably reject your app because of using registered names (such as Batman or Superman) of Marvel, DC Comics, etc. :)

Comment: @Kashiv: The names are just an example

Comment: Dan F: Nothing is displayed in my TableView

Comment: NSLog "[[Singleton sharedInstance] movies]" and see what the dictionaries contain - there probably is no key "title"

Comment: @David H: That's the first thing I tought but the key "title" is correct, I doubled check.

Comment: @ARFIRST according to the code you posted "title" is not a key in your dictionaries

Comment: OK - so you say that the dictionary has an object for @"title" but its not showing. So you need to use a NSString *title, assign it to that first, log it, then "cell.textLabel.text = title;, then log NSLog(@"Cell title=%@", cell.textLabel.text). Something is going to be nil. If its not nil, then the text color is white or something so even if the title is set you cannot see it - or you have covered your cell titles with some other object. You could first do something like "cell.textLabel.text = @"FOO";", run your app, see if you see FOO in the cell.

Comment: @ARFIRST you also don't have a member or method named "movies" in the `Singleton` class

Comment: @DavidH I'll try that when I get home, Thanks!

Comment: @DanF That's because this is just an example, I modified the actual names that I'm using, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that your arrays and dictionaries are not being retained properly.  Try adding a `retain` call to your init method:

```
-(id) init {

    if (self=[super init]) {

        batman = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                             @"name", @"Back to the Future", 
                             @"year", @"1985", nil] retain];

        superman = [[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"name", @"Superman", 
                    @"year", @"1990", nil] retain];

        superheroes = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:batman,superman, nil] retain]; 
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: hey @Dan F, does it matter that I'm using ARC?

Comment: @ARFIRST It would matter, but I assumed you weren't because you declared the properties as `retain` in your code above instead of `strong`.  If that is still the case (that you are using ARC and the properties are still `retain` try changing them to `strong` instead

Comment: @ARFIRST sorry if I confused you with my first comment, I edited it.  Coffee hasn't fully kicked in yet this morning, I misread your comment originally

Comment: Someone just mentiones to me what's wrong with it. it's object and keys, I should use   @"Back to the Future", @"name" instead of @"name", @"Back to the Future"

Comment: @ARFIRST Ah yes, a common mistake, you list object first, then the key with it.

Comment: Yes! That was it! Now the problem is I want to set an image that I have in the Dictionary, I tried: cell.imageView.image = [[[[Singleton sharedInstance] movies]   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  objectForKey:@"image"]; but I have to set the uiimage somehow

Comment: Now I tried: cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[[[Singleton sharedInstance] movies]   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  objectForKey:@"image"]]; still no good